# Validation in a terraform variable makes a plan fail while it shouldn't

Tags: terraform, yaml

I have a module that accepts a variable with a validation as follows

```
variable "policy_statements" {
  description = "The statements of the policies to be created"
  type = map(object({
    path         = string
    capabilities = set(string)
  }))

validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for stmt in var.policy_statements :
      contains(["create", "read", "update", "patch", "delete", "list"], stmt.capabilities)
    ])
    error_message = "Valid values for capabilities are (\"create\", \"read\", \"update\", \"patch\", \"delete\", \"list\")."
  }
```

I am then calling this module from another tf module:

```
module "policies" {
  source = "../../../../path/to"

  for_each = var.policies

  policy_statements = each.value

}
```

In the outer module, the `policies` variable is declared as

```
variable "policies" {
  description = "The statements of the policies to be created"
  type           = map(any)
}
```

Invocation fails with:

```
│ Error: Invalid value for variable
│
│   on main.tf line 38, in module "policies":
│   38:   policy_statements = each.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.policy_statements is map of object with 2 elements
│
│ Valid values for capabilities are ("create", "read", "update", "patch",
│ "delete", "list").
│
│ This was checked by the validation rule at
│ ../../../../modules-terraform/vault/policies/variables.tf:12,3-13.
```

The outer module reads the `policies` variable in a `terragrunt.hcl` as below:

```
locals {
  policies = yamldecode(file("config.yaml"))
}

inputs = {
  policies = local.policies
}
```

where `config.yaml`

```yaml
policies:
  policy-test-1:
    capabilities:
      - read
      - create
    path: /foo/lala
  policy-test-2:
    capabilities:
      - update
      - delete
    path: /foo/lala
```

What troubles me is that removing the validation makes the plan succeed.

What am I doing wrong in the validation?

Comment: I see you made a new question. Is your old issue solved by using `local.policies.policies`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top level key in the yaml file is `policies`, but you are not reading it. So it should be:

```
policies = local.policies.policies
```